# Hyperledger fabric certificate validation with certificate transparency

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

This is a theoretical question about certificate validation in Hyperledger Fabric. How does Fabric handle a scenario like a compromised certificate authority? Does it monitor public log servers to ensure a certificate is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificate Revocation Lists

A Certificate Revocation List (CRL) is easy to understand — it’s just a list of references to certificates that a CA knows to be revoked for one reason or another. If you recall the store scenario, a CRL would be like a list of stolen credit cards.

When a third party wants to verify another party’s identity, it first checks the issuing CA’s CRL to make sure that the certificate has not been revoked. A verifier doesn’t have to check the CRL, but if they don’t they run the risk of accepting a compromised identity.

Using a CRL to check that a certificate is still valid. If an impersonator tries to pass a compromised digital certificate to a validating party, it can be first checked against the issuing CA’s CRL to make sure it’s not listed as no longer valid.

link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/identity/identity.html#certificate-revocation-lists

Generating a CRL (Certificate Revocation List)

After a certificate is revoked in the Fabric CA server, the appropriate MSPs in Hyperledger Fabric must also be updated. This includes both local MSPs of the peers as well as MSPs in the appropriate channel configuration blocks. To do this, PEM encoded CRL (certificate revocation list) file must be placed in the crls folder of the MSP. The fabric-ca-client gencrl command can be used to generate a CRL. Any identity with hf.GenCRL attribute can create a CRL that contains serial numbers of all certificates that were revoked during a certain period. The created CRL is stored in the /crls/crl.pem file.

The following command will create a CRL containing all the revoked certficates (expired and unexpired) and store the CRL in the ~/msp/crls/crl.pem file.

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=~/clientconfig
fabric-ca-client gencrl -M ~/msp
```

The next command will create a CRL containing all certificates (expired and unexpired) that were revoked after 2017-09-13T16:39:57-08:00 (specified by the –revokedafter flag) and before 2017-09-21T16:39:57-08:00 (specified by the –revokedbefore flag) and store the CRL in the ~/msp/crls/crl.pem file.

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=~/clientconfig
fabric-ca-client gencrl --caname "" --revokedafter 2017-09-13T16:39:57-08:00 --revokedbefore 2017-09-21T16:39:57-08:00 -M ~/msp
```

The –caname flag specifies the name of the CA to which this request is sent. In this example, the gencrl request is sent to the default CA.

The –revokedafter and –revokedbefore flags specify the lower and upper boundaries of a time period. The generated CRL will contain certificates that were revoked in this time period. The values must be UTC timestamps specified in RFC3339 format. The –revokedafter timestamp cannot be greater than the –revokedbefore timestamp.

By default, ‘Next Update’ date of the CRL is set to next day. The crl.expiry CA configuration property can be used to specify a custom value.

The gencrl command will also accept –expireafter and –expirebefore flags that can be used to generate a CRL with revoked certificates that expire during the period specified by these flags. For example, the following command will generate a CRL that contains certificates that were revoked after 2017-09-13T16:39:57-08:00 and before 2017-09-21T16:39:57-08:00, and that expire after 2017-09-13T16:39:57-08:00 and before 2018-09-13T16:39:57-08:00

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=~/clientconfig
fabric-ca-client gencrl --caname "" --expireafter 2017-09-13T16:39:57-08:00 --expirebefore 2018-09-13T16:39:57-08:00  --revokedafter 2017-09-13T16:39:57-08:00 --revokedbefore 2017-09-21T16:39:57-08:00 -M ~/msp
```

link: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#generating-a-crl-certificate-revocation-list

Besides that, Hyperledger Fabric provides Pluggable Consensus Protocol and the security is depends on your plugable MSP too.

Comment: This includes both local MSPs of the peers as well as MSPs in the appropriate channel configuration blocks. Then how to update the local msps of peer?